# How to avoid re renders when using rtk query in react native

Tags: redux, rtk-query

I am using rtk query with below logic

```
 if(isSuccess){
    console.log("success")
     storeToken(data.token)
    dispatch(login())
}
```

But this code causing too many re renders causing error in react native

Comment: Can you share the code of the full component around this? Depending on where you write it, you write a side effect as part of the render - triggering an infinite loop. But it's impossible to say for sure with that minimal amount of information you give here.

Comment: hey i solved this triggering dipatch() when api response is isSuccess causing this

Comment: Your problem is likely triggering during render and not in an effect - or in an effect with a wrong dependency array. `isSuccess` is not triggering it in any way - your code is. Please share more code.

Comment: hi can you please help solve this i ams tuck here since days i have provided all the details in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74787908/redux-working-in-debug-mode-but-not-in-release-apk-in-react-native

Comment: Pretty much impossible. That is not "all detail" and definitely not enough to debug this. You are asking a very broad question and providing very little context. Either you create a reproduction, or you narrow down the problem to something a *lot* more specific, e.g. to a single variable not having the value you want it to have. `console.log` is your friend to get there.